# Can't connect MySQL + Springboot in Docker container

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

Been looking for a solution to this problem but can't seem to find anything that helps me resolve. I'm trying to launch my Springboot Demo project with docker-compose which should connect it to a MYSQL container but the connection fails to start. Both images are successfully created but the Springboot app container immediately. Here are my configuration files and I'm on a Apple Silicon computer.

application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/localspringbootdb?autoReconnect=true&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
    username: admin
    password: root
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
  sql:
    init:
      mode: always
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:17
WORKDIR /opt
ENV PORT 8080
EXPOSE 8080
COPY target/*.jar /opt/app.jar
ENTRYPOINT exec java $JAVA_OPTS -jar app.jar
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    image: thisnickg194/docker17:0.0.1
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://db:3306/localspringbootdb?autoReconnect=true&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: admin
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: root
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: arm64v8/mysql:8-oracle
    environment:
      DATABASE_HOST: docker-mysql
      DATABASE_PORT: 3306
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: localspringbootdb
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
```

And Pom dependencies

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I've tried re running the app while the DB was running but get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

just add -ports in db service, how you did for app service in your docker compose